# Why is jQuery autocomplete not popping up?

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

Here's the condensed source code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
        <link href="/media/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/admin/js/core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/admin/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/admin/js/actions.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery.autocomplete.pack.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div>
            <label for="id_postal_code" class="required">Postal code:</label>
            <input type="text" name="postal_code" id="id_postal_code" />
            <script>$('#id_postal_code').autocomplete({source:['one','two','three']});</script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to type 'o' in the textbox, but nothing appears.

It's adding this `autocomplete='off'` attribute and `class='ac_input'` to the input, so... it seems to be initializing correctly, I just don't know why anything isn't appearing.

If I look at the source code in firefox, that `ac_input` flashes every time I hit a key too, so it seems to be setting the class every time I type something, but autocomplete never switches to "on" (which I'm guessing it ought to at some point?).

Comment: Shouldn't $('#id_postal_code').autocomplete({source:['one','two','three']}); be wrapped in a $(document).ready()?

Comment: @Gazler: Thought I wouldn't have to if I put it *after* the element. That should ensure that the element has loaded, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `{source:['one','two','three']}` with `['one','two','three']`.

Comment: What the heck?? That's not what their example shows (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) but it does seem to be working now. Wonder why that is... (thank you)

Comment: I had a problem with autocomplete not working, too. However, this solution didn't work for me. In fact it made things worse: I got a runtime error because the `source` property is undefined. In my case, I'm enhancing a jQuery element that is not yet put into the document flow and that seems to be the issue. By delaying the enhancement until after I insert the element into the DOM, I got it to work. But, passing in just and array like this simply doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Ates: Just figured out why....I was loading the wrong version of autocomplete! I was using the old one from bassistance.de, but I *thought* I was using the new one from jQuery UI. They're both in my JS folder :\

Comment: @Ates, can you give me the link from where you downloaded the autocomplete script please

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your call inside

```
$(function() { 
  // your code here... 
});
```

It looks like your DOM isn't ready yet.

Comment: Nope, changed it to `$(function(){$('#id_postal_code').autocomplete({source:['one','two','three']});});` and it made no difference.

Answer (score 2):

You initialize jQuery twice -- admin/jquery.min.js and js/jquery-1.4.4.js

Try fixing that.

Comment: Django adds one of them, but it sets `noConflict`, so I should be able to have two copies.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the solutions above or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026592/jquery-ui-autocomplete-is-automatically-turned-off) solve this issue, be sure to check the page markup for a `ul.ui-autocomplete` element and check the `z-index`. In my case the plugin was working fine, the element was positioned correctly, but the z-index needed to be bumped up.